# Can i change the leaflet popup position

Tags: leaflet

i have a leaflet project (1.2.0) with markers and popups on it. I want to change the popup position to find the best place to show the popup.

For example:

- When the marker is on the left side of the map, show the popup right beside the marker
- When the marker is on the right side of the map, show the popup left beside the marker
- When the marker is on the top of the map, show the popup below
- When the marker in on the bottom of the map, show it over the marker

I want to show the popup with changing the map state. When i set the keepInView property to false, the map doesn't change, but the popup is not completely visible when the marker is on the edge of the map.

Thanks for your help :-)

Regards,
Matthias

Comment: You really should check out the [list of Leaflet plugins](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#search--popups) and, in particular, https://github.com/yafred/leaflet-responsive-popup and http://erictheise.com/rrose/

Comment: @IvanSanchez doesn't works for me :"default.a.responsivePopup is not a function"